# BigTable: 2 Writes to the same key, but 3 versions

Tags: bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

Sometimes If I write multiple versions onto the same row key, and with multiple column families within multiple batched mutations (each version is batched together with multiple writes).

[image]

Is this expected behavior due to data compaction? Will the extra version be removed over time?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you're doing this batching and which client you're using? Take a look at the internal API here: https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/reference/data/rpc/google.bigtable.v2#mutaterowsrequest. My suspicion is that you're putting the two columns in two separate entries in the batch, which means that even if they have the same row they won't be applied atomically. At that point it's possible for one write to succeed and the other to time out (succeeding silently), at which point retry behavior might write it again.

Comment: @DouglasMcErlean Yep, I think you are right. I think I resolved this issue by placing a time instead of setting it to None when I perform batch mutation.

Comment: That will make the retries use the same timestamp, but another thing you probably want is for the updates to actually be atomic within the row. Two changes to the same row can be specified in the same batch element, which will accomplish this. Right now you're essentially sending two separate mutations within the batch.

Comment: @DouglasMcErlean Is there a tutorial on this? The GCP documentation shows mutations done within a list.

Comment: Can you link to the documentation you're looking at? I'd like to clean it up if it's unclear. For example I see the go samples (https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/samples-go-hello#writing_rows_to_a_table) don't show that you can do multiple Set() calls on a single mutation, but in fact that's allowed and encouraged.

Comment: These are the documentation I've used: https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigtable/index.html, https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/samples-python-hello

Comment: Thanks, I've filed internal feedback to highlight multiple sets on a single mutation! In the example on that page you'd simply call set_cell more than once on the same object to make multiple changes to a row atomically.

Comment: @DouglasMcErlean I’ve changed my code to use set cell more than once, and it works.

Comment: @DouglasMcErlean Mind writing an answer? I’m not sure if many people who tried it knows this feature exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you're putting the two columns in two separate entries in the batch, which means that even if they have the same row they won't be applied atomically.

Batch entries can succeed or fail individually, and the client will then retry just the failed entries. If, for example, one entry succeeds and the other times out but later succeeds silently, a retry of the "failed" entry can lead to the partial write results you're seeing.

In python you should therefore do something like the following (adapted from cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/samples-python-hello):

```py
print('Writing some greetings to the table.')
greetings = ['Hello World!', 'Hello Cloud Bigtable!', 'Hello Python!']
rows = []
column1 = 'greeting1'.encode()
column1 = 'greeting2'.encode()
for i, value in enumerate(greetings):
    # Note: This example uses sequential numeric IDs for simplicity,
    # but this can result in poor performance in a production
    # application.  Since rows are stored in sorted order by key,
    # sequential keys can result in poor distribution of operations
    # across nodes.
    #
    # For more information about how to design a Bigtable schema for
    # the best performance, see the documentation:
    #
    #     https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design
    row_key = 'greeting{}'.format(i).encode()
    row = table.row(row_key)

    # **Multiple calls to 'set_cell()' are allowed on the same batch
    # entry. Each entry will be applied atomically, but a separate
    # 'row' in the same batch will be applied separately even if it
    # shares its row key with another entry.**
    row.set_cell(column_family_id,
                 column1,
                 value,
                 timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
    row.set_cell(column_family_id,
                 column2,
                 value,
                 timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
    rows.append(row)
table.mutate_rows(rows)
```